# How to make <div> inline? All <div>, even when their total width more than width of their parent?

Tags: css, html, inline

I need to make `<div>` displayed inline and hide them with "overflow: hidden" for their parent.

Width for `<div>` is set to 20% with "box-sizing" property, so they are exactly 20% of their parent width.

The usual method, using "float: left" doesn't help, because it makes only 5 `<div>` displayed in one line, and the rest of them shown in new line under the first 5 `<div>`.

How to make all `<div>` displayd inline and hide the rest of them if they are too wide to be shown inside of their parent, using "overflow: hidden"?

I have the following document structure:

```
<body>
<div class="column">
    <div class="header">Some text</div>

    <ul class="item_list">
        <li class="simple"><a href="">Some text<br></a></li>
        <li class="simple"><a href="">Some text<br></a></li>
        <li class="simple"><a href="">Some text<br></a></li>
        ...
    </ul> 
</div>
```

You can see what I mean [here](http://raj-timetable.fvds.ru/admin/). But I've made it using javascript (setted for `<div>` "position: absolute" and generated "margin-left" for each elemet) and it causes great problems for future development.

Comment: Have you tried `display:inline` and `clear:none`?

Comment: Of course, but I need fixed width of the elements (20%) and width of inline elements depends on their content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/7YDfE/3/

Use `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` in combination:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inline"></div>
    <div class="inline"></div>
    <div class="inline"></div>
</div>
```

Then use the appropriate CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
    width: 200px; /* or whatever */
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The demo contains a little jQuery animation to illustrate the effect:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/7YDfE/3/

Comment: Bear in mind that `display: inline-block` isn't supported for [non 'naturally inline' elements](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03) in IE 6, and incompletely in IE 7.

Comment: In my tests `display: inline` does not provide the desired effect on divs: http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/emBjM/1/

Comment: Thanks! `inline-block` and `nowrap` works great, but how to delete appeared whitespaces between elements? The only way I've found is to wride code in one line: http://jsfiddle.net/2QZeB/1/

Comment: It is a factor of whitespace in the markup, the solution is to remove any whitespace inbetween the elements: http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/7YDfE/5/

Comment: I know this is old: I added an answer based on your whitespace issue below. Code doesn't show well in comments.

Answer (score 1):

If the `div` elements are `display: inline` then applying `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent element will prevent their wrapping to new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a known number of divs, have you tried using absolute positioning instead of floats, and specifying left:20% left:40%, etc.?

Comment: Yes, it is the end of my question)) and I don't know the amount of <div>'s, they generated by the server using database.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the container `div`'s height to a fixed value, and give all the inner elements `display: inline-block`, this should do the trick. `inline-block` will make each element align to the left, but keep it's dimensions, while the fixed height container will hide any that overflow to a new line.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want with the addition of removing the white space between while allowing nice code formatting. The container gets font-size:0px ftw.

Markup

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inline">Some text </div>
    <div class="inline">Some sample text </div>
    <div class="inline">Some Other text </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrapper {
    width: 250px; /* or whatever */
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size:0px;
}

div.inline {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size:12px;
}
```